# Trouble installing SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate

I'm trying to rapidSSL certificate for a IIS hosted website - something is going horribly wrong.

I've tried to reissue twice now - the process I'm going through is this:

- Using the IIS wizard, Create new Certifiacte
- Generate local CSR
- Copy paste the CSR into the RapidSSL reissue window
- RapidSSL sends me a new Cert
- I create a txt file and paste the contents
- I attempt to complete the pending request and provide the response.txt file.

I get the error:

"The pending certificate request for this response file was not found. This request may be 
canceled.  You cannot install selected response certificate using this Wizard."

I've ensured that the hostname on the CSR request matches the hostname entered in the RapidSSL renewal form.

I've checked that there aren't any extra whitespace characters in the reponse.cer file, and ensured that the certificate header and footers are copied correctly.

I'm really struggling.

Ashley

Answer (score 1):

That sounds to be like you don't have the certificate request file on hand, or have since done a second request which overwrote the first private key. You might be able to reinstall the CSR under pending with the certmgr.msc application.

Comment: I did re-create the request and send the new CSR to RapidSSL using their Reissue tool.

I still get the error message.

I suspect the cert was registered initially as www.example.com
and my request didn't have the www. prefix.

Would this matter?

Comment: Yes it would. It has to match exactly. example.com and www.example.com are two different common names as far as SSL is concerned. (unless you're using wildcard certs, which you're not). My suggestion would be to issue a new cert request file from IIS using the exact name you want to use and then use the same name at RapidSSL.

Comment: Here are some hopefully helpful links:

https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO6444&actp=LIST

https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO5757

http://www.rapidssl.com/ssl-certificate-support/generate-csr/microsoft_IIS_5.htm

https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO10516

Comment: Thanks Joeqwerty,

No good.  I've checked that i'm using www.example.com when generating the CSR request and when entering that CSR on the RapidShare reissue page.  

Say - the response i get from RapidShare is an email not with an .cer attachment, but a text block that has the following


----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...

----- END CERTIFICATE-----

The IIS renewal wizard demands a .cer file, do i just paste it into notepad and save as reponse.cer?

Thanks!!

Ashley

Comment: Pasting it into response.cer should work. Just make sure that line wrapping is off. :)

Comment: Waaaah :_(  yep - still no good.  

I did have word wrap enabled - I tried removing all the line breaks.

Sadly to no avail.  

I'm cutting and pasting the text via RDP - perhaps the values are getting manged.

Thanks all.

Comment: Make sure you use notepad and make sure to remove any leading or trailing spaces, then save the text as a .cer file.

Comment: Also, make sure not to remove any text. The " ----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- " and the "----- END CERTIFICATE-----" need to be there.

Comment: Hmmm... yep - it still fails.  oh dear.  Does text encoding matter?  I'm using ANSI